# how to design hbase index table?

Tags: hbase

I need to design an index table in Hbase. For example, my main table is like this:

```
Person
row key: uuid --> name and address columns
```

I need to create an index Person_Name_Index table which map name with Person key. My index table will look like:

```
Person_Name_Index
row key: name --> person row key
```

What is the efficient way to insert multiple person row key to a row key name in Person_Name_Index? I can make all the person row keys to be a single value, but if I need to add another person row key to a name. I have to read all of them and then add a new item to it. If I make each person row key to be in a separate column, i need to make sure the name are unique. I don't know how to do that without using uuid type string which makes my table large as well. Any idea or suggestion?

Thanks,

Comment: You're probably doing something wrong, I don't understand the goal of the Person_Name_Index table. Why you want to map name with person row key? In Hbase, you are supposed to denormalize your data. If you don't denormalized your data, you basically end up with the same implementation you use on an RDBMS. I don't know your use case but it probably has a solution where all this data would be in the same table

Comment: I want to find all the user with a given name. I can scan through my person table but it is more efficient to scan through an index table, isn't it?

Comment: What is your use case for the person table? You should maybe put the name as the row key of the person table and put all the addresses in a single column family

Comment: Name is not guarantee unique. I can't do that.

Comment: Yes but at the end what's the difference between adding multiple person row keys in a Person_Name_Index row or adding multiple person addresses in a Person row. I mean it is the same thing but you only have one table

Comment: The difference is the row key. The Person has row key is uuid. The Person_Name_Index has row key is the name. The indexed on name in Person_Name_Index makes searching by name a lot faster. Is that the point of creating an index table? What is your suggestion on searching by name from Person table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Sean said in HBase it is recommended to model the data according to they access paths you need. It isn't recommended to treat it as an RDBMS (since it isn't). In you case you can ,ake the key of the person table as the Name followed by a delimited (e.g. pipe) and then the  UID - then you can search by name and have a unique ID per person

```
String personName="Name to Search";
String delimiter="|";
PrefixFilter prefixFilter = new PrefixFilter(Bytes.toBytes(personName+delimiter));
Scan scan = new Scan();
scan.setFilter(prefixFilter);
ResultScanner resultScanner = hBaseTable.getScanner(scan);
```

And then iterate on the scanner to see all the people with the name

Comment: I use uuid as column family for the index table instead of combining them. A row in the index table will look like : name --> muliple (uuid, person). Do you see any problem with that approach?

Comment: The problem is that you'd have to make two calls to get to the data instead of a single call. HBase sorts the data lexicographically according to the key and you can scan using a PrefixFilter (I'll edit the reply to add an example)

Comment: what is the value of "name"+"|"+uuid ? Is that a person or an empty value.

Comment: That would be a complete person record

Comment: A range scan would have better performance here than a prefixfilter- ie set the start and stop rows. Start row being the name to search, and stop row being the name to search with the last byte incremented by 1. The prefix filter is going to scan all of the data in the table.

Comment: you're right - I didn't correct this since that's what the second answer already mentioned